# Uploading an image, AngularJS, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am uploading an image using the following code in AngularJS:

HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <input type="file" ngf-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
//inject angular file upload directive.
angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', 'Upload', function($scope, Upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var $file = $files[i];
      Upload.upload({
        url: 'src/assets',
        file: $file,
        progress: function(e){}
      }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      }); 
    }
  }
}];
```

when I run it and try to upload an image I get this error:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

So it's complaining about the POST method to save the file into the destination folder which apparently is not allowed, any ideas ???  or does someone have an easier way to upload an image into the site folder in angular ??  thanks a lot !!

Comment: Well this sounds like a server problem. The server is rejecting your POST request as you said. What does the handler on the server-side look like?

Comment: Hi Hopeful, I have checked this for the staticfile handler and it's setup to allow all verbs GET, POST,PUT,DELETE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now sorted, 
Issue was that the URL was wrong, after reviewing the Controller/ActionMethod that does the upload on the server side I then realized that the url to call is actually

myUploads/ImageUpload

I can now upload images into my Angular application without any problem !! :)